# Dictionary autocompletion in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, code-completion

Do you know how I can auto-complete dictionary keys the same way that it works for objects and methods in PyCharm? Is there such a feature?

Answer (score 7):

Simply press **[Ctrl / Cmd]+[Space]**

[image]

Comment: What if that combination is reserved for something else outside of PyCharm?

Comment: @Yoda What do you mean, can you give an example?